# How to run UWP background tasks in seperate processes?

Tags: uwp, background-process, background-task

In an app that declares multiple different background task extensions, how can I control which tasks can share a hosting process and which ones can not - for the purpose of resource separation and stability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **ResourceGroup** property on the Extension node to specify which tasks can run together vs need to be run in a separate process:

```
  <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.SessionConnectedTriggerTask" 
               ResourceGroup="foo">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.TimeZoneTriggerTask" 
               ResourceGroup="foo">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="systemEvent" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.TimerTriggerTask" 
               ResourceGroup="bar">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="timer" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.ApplicationTriggerTask" 
               ResourceGroup="bar">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="general" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" 
               EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.MaintenanceTriggerTask" 
               ResourceGroup="foobar">
      <BackgroundTasks>
        <Task Type="general" />
      </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
  </Extensions>
```